# An equality about an infimum over a vector: $\inf_y = \inf_{\|v\|=1}\inf_t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

I am reading convex optimization [lecture notes](https://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf), where I saw the equality as a part of the derivation:

[image]

Here $f$ is a function and $\nabla f$ is the gradient. What seems to happen here is that the author replaces $(y-z) = t v$ with $\|v \| = 1$ and converts infimum over $y$ to double infimum (is this trivial? i.e. infimum over multiplication equals taking a double infimum?). What confuses me further here is, with that, now $z$ depends on $v$ and I don't understand how this works, or I'm overthinking. Could anyone provide a proof for this? Is this a well-known technique?

Comment: $z$ doesn't need to depend on $v$. Since for any $z$ and any $t $ and $v$, we find the $y$ and for any $z$ and $y$ we find the $t > 0$ and $v$, we can hold $z$ still and vary over $y$ or [$v$ and $t$].

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm also not sure why (in a simplified case) $\inf_y = \inf_{\|v\|=1} \inf_t$ in the first place (i.e. I see if we use $y = t v$ for a unit-norm $v$, then $\inf_y = \inf_{t v}$, is it obvious that we can sort infimum in any way we want? Also I'm not sure I follow your comment, I'd appreciate a more detailed answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are taking the infimum of a certain quantity over *the same* set.

Comment: @Matematleta: Your immediate comment above is enlightening because I'm way less confused that I was originally. Thank you. But I'm still slightly confused. How can the norm of $v$  be set equal to 1 and one still be sure that the second infimum is not being constrained unfairly ( compared to the original equation ).

Comment: Set $z=0$ for convenience. Then, for each $y$ there is a $t$ and a unit vector $v$ such that $y=tv$ so infing over $y$ is the same thing as infing over $t$ for all unit vectors $v$. Obviously this needs to be made rigorous.

Comment: @Matematleta. I see it when you say set z = 0 for convenience. But is that okay to do ? That won't change the inf either ? I guess not. If that is the case but it's complicated to explain or show, don't worry about it. Thanks for your help. I understand it a lot more than I did when it was first stated.

Comment: Hint: in general $\inf \: \{ u_{\alpha\beta} : \alpha \in A, \beta \in B\} = \inf_{\beta\in B} \inf\: \{u_{\alpha\beta} : \alpha \in A\} = \inf_{\alpha\in A} \inf\: \{ u_{\alpha\beta} : \beta \in B\}.$

Comment: While this obviously was a  good exercise (thanks flukx), I realised (way too late) that simple minimisation of the first line and plugging resulting $y^\star$ in the expression results in the same bound (as in the slides 1.14). The author seems to be focusing on $\|\cdot\|_*$ norm and that's the reason of all this infimum conversion trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the step from $y$ to $v$, let's make us aware that the notation in the lecture notes doesn't print from which set the possible $y$'s come from since it's "obvious". It's $ℝ^n$. Writing this explicitly might make it clearer how to get from $y$ to $w = tv$:
$$
\inf_{y ∈ ℝ^n} g(y) = \inf_{w ∈ ℝ^n - z} g(w + z)
$$
Here $ℝ^n - z = \{y - z | y ∈ ℝ^n\}$. The operation $· - z$ is a bijection and by applying the inverse operation to the argument of the $\inf$-ed function it is hopefully clear that we take the infimum over the same values.

We use this for $g(y) = f(z) + ∇f(z)^T(y-z) + \frac{L}2 \|y-z\|^2$. So after cancelling the $z$'s we have $g(w + z) = f(z) + ∇f(z)^Tw + \frac L2 \|w\|^2$.

Concerning your worry about dependence of $z$: it is a number like $2$ or $L$. That's why @Matematleta said "set $z=0$ for convenience". $0$ is one possible value for $z$ but all other possible values work the same way.

Now we replace $w$ by $tv$ with $t ∈ ℝ_{≥ 0}$ and $v ∈ ^{n-1} := \{ν ∈ ℝ^n | \|ν\| = 1\}$. We can find for every $w$ such $v$ and $t$ and other way around as well. (It's not a bijection since $0v = 0v'$ even for $v \neq v'$.)

Now to show that the $\inf$'s are interchangeable, take the definition of $\inf$: one part is that it is a lower bound. That means $$∀α∈ A : \inf_{a ∈ A} g(a) ≤ g(α)$$. The other part is, that the $\inf$ is the highest lower bound, so $$∀ α ∈ A: X ≤ g(α) ⇒ X ≤ \inf_{a∈A} g(a)$$. Use this:
$$
\begin{align}
&∀ ν∈ ^{n-1} :& \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(v, t) &≤ \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(ν, t)  \\
⇒ &∀ ν ∈ ^{n-1} : ∀τ ∈ ℝ :& \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(v, t) &≤ \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(ν, t) ≤ h(ν, τ) \\
⇒ &∀τ ∈ ℝ : ∀ ν ∈ ^{n-1} :& \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(v, t) &≤ h(ν, τ) \\
⇒ &∀τ ∈ ℝ :& \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(v, t) &≤ \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} h(v, τ) \\
⇒ && \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(v, t) &≤ \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} h(v, t)
\end{align}
$$
We can do the same argument with $v$ and $t$ exchanged and get
$$
\inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(v, t) ≤ \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} h(v, t) ≤ \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(v, t) \\
⇒ \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} h(v, t) = \inf_{t ∈ ℝ} \inf_{v ∈ ^{n-1}} h(v, t)
$$